# Azure Web Site: Could not load file or assembly - which dependency files are really missing?

Tags: asp.net, azure, dll, dependencies, webrole

In my asp.net project, I need to reference a third party legacy C++ component. The component is normally installed on local machine, and the web app runs fine on my local host - in fact, my web app only uses one dll of this big component. Now, I want to deploy the app to azure website. As I figured out, I have to use azure web role to run tasks in a startup script. However, I tried many ways and nothing seems to work. I got the same error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.Foundation.IO.DLL' or one of its
>   dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

Using dependency walker, it seems me that foundation.io.dll has only two custom dependencies: **fileio.dll** and **fregistry.dll**. All other files seem to be system files, probably from vcredist_x86.exe. However, I tried to deploy those files to azure cloud service, and problem is not resolved.

I uploaded those three files in a shared service at [here](http://www.fileswap.com/folder/IdHlWwR6/). I wonder if somebody could take a look? Your time is much appreciated.

By the way, my startup script looks like this:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
vcredist_x86.exe /q /norestart
exit /b 0
```

The fileio.dll and fregistry.dll, vcredist_x86.exe, and this startup script are included in asp.net project's bin folder using 'copy always'.

Comment: Visual Studio usually indicates missing libs during package process - in output window. Do you see something there?

Comment: Well, it doesn't in this case, maybe because this third party dll includes a COM component.